# ios UITableViewController elements with childs

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I wish to generate a navigation-list.

I Have a UITableViewController and i would that if a cell is clicked the child's of the cell where displayed in the UITabeViewController and a back-button should appear.

Currently for tests i do/did this:

```
var anz = 10
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return anz
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if anz<10 {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    anz = 5
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But there is no back-button (of course).

So it should look like:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by child's of the Cell?

Comment: A data structure like catergory's a category can have a "child"-category

Comment: do you want a back-button in the cell, or in the navigation bar?
is this code in a view controller class? is this viewcontroller a child of the navigationcontroller? please provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to make collapsible / expandable table view.

you could refer http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: Thank u! But that is not what i am looking for, every category can have x category's and this can have x child category's and this can.... and so on...

Comment: By setting up plist file for n number root elements you can manage your category and subcategory and so on.

Comment: An will there a back button if an category is choisen?

Comment: Yes, by setting up plist programatically as per webservices / db you can retrive. i guess no need for back button, by tapping on category again will unexpand sub category list.

Answer (score 0):

I've used such extension in my project to handle navigation back button

```
extension UIViewController {
    var shouldShowBackButton: Bool {
        get {
            return navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(self) > 0
        }
    }
}
```

and in your UIViewController child

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if shouldShowBackButton {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named: "land_back"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "pop")
    } else {
        navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what is mean by this: "return navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(self) > 0" or how can i change this?

Comment: navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named: "land_back"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "pop") don't show any button!

Comment: could you please make sure that you have the resource (asset) with "back" name. it's custom back button. you should have it in case of leftBarButtonItem customization

Comment: typically you should not change the "return navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(self) > 0" it will work for all view controllers, but if in some cases according your design requirements you will need to update this behaviour you can simply override this var and return false.

Comment: ok i think i got it! But the code `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named: "land_back"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "pop")` doesn't show an back button.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manage a condition here 
1. first add a back button on navigation bar and hide it.
2 . when you select the cell of table view than change the tag no or increase the count to manage the condition.
3. soups yo have 2 array , you load the first array on table view and when user select the cell from table view then you increase the tag no and reload the tableview on that time you have to manage a tag 2 condition to load the 2nd array on table view and manage the back button and its action to reduce the count.

Answer (score 0):

To have back button in navigation bar you need to push your controller.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if anz<10 {
       navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    anz = 5
      let vc = YourViewController with custom INIT where you can pass anz
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Here **YourViewController** is your current view controller with table view you are showing in picture.

Comment: Sorry i really new at ios but what ur a re mean with "YourViewController"

Comment: Your view controller class where you have above code which you mentioned in your question :)